# Process Start on VB 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

I try to do multiple string at multiple textbox. When process process start button, the string inside the textbox will combine into one and run it. Here my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = "192.168.0.1"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

  Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox4.Text = TextBox3.Text & TextBox1.Text & TextBox1.Text()
    Process.Start(TextBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

i wish to make the command the textbox4.text like this

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.0.1 "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

I know that there is wrong in this code but i just dont know which part. Is there any other simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to pass the other textboxes values as argument.

Process.Start has an overload that accepts an argument paramter: [See this for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So something like this is what you want:

```
Process.Start(Textbox2.text, Textbox3.text + " " + TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it solve the problem but the code above make the command C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.0.1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe. i need the quotation at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"